# facebook like button won't allow comment

Tags: web, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

I've added the like button to my website trying both the XFBML and HTML5 versions and all three forms of the button layouts to try to fix this problem.  People can like my website, but there is no working comment box.  Strangely, it worked last night, but a friend called me this morning that the comment box comes up, they could type a comment, but nothing at all happens when they click to post it.  I tried it again myself and the comment box flashes up for a split second, only to disappear again without the possibility of leaving a comment.

I am quite knowledgable with coding and I've followed the steps exactly, plugging the generated code into my html as directed.  For the XFBML, the generated JS SDK code has been plugged in right after the opening body tag, I've added the xmlns:fb-"http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" code into the html tag, and added the button code in my content code.  My data is being recorded in Insights and it even shows that a few comments were recorded yesterday. Any ideas what could be wrong all of a sudden?
Thanks in advance.
Lori